# Magento tax issue, tax being applied twice

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a Magento Store, running 1.7.0.2 CE edition.

We are setting up tax for Australia (GST). The tax is 10%.

It seems that the orders are adding our tax component twice.

Important: Now the order has a 50% catalog price rule used also. And not applied to shipping.

Screen shot of order can be viewed here: http://www.jasonshico.com/screenshot.jpg (see screen1 heading)

As you can see, I believe the GST(10%) has been added again, even though you see the products above the products include tax.

Here are some of my magneto settings:

1. (see screen2 heading on above screenshot link)
2. (see screen3 heading on above screenshot link)

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following changes to your Tax Settings:

```
1. Tax Calculation Method Based On: Total

2. Catalog and Shipping Prices: Excluding Tax
```

Don't ignore such warnings:

```
Warning tax discount configuration might result in different discounts than a customer might expect .
```

Follow this article: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-ce-18-ee-113-tax-calc

Comment: hi thanks for your input Harit. But if I was to set catalogue to excluding tax wont that show up on the front end with prices of products without tax?

Comment: hi harit, in australia we have to include tax on the front end. not sure if excluding tax is going to work. secondly, please tell me if i was to change to Tax Calculation Method Based On: Total from Unit price as it is now, what implications would it have? and if I used alex's suggestion below inconjunction with your first suggestion, wonder if that will work?

Comment: hi harit, just wondering if you had a chance to review my last comment? keen to touch base

Answer (score 0):

Please use this settings : After Discount for Apply Customer Tax option in screen2.

Your issue causes by that option. Now you are using the 50% discount and applies the tax before discount, so the tax will be applied to the original total.
It is just issue.

So you must use After Discount option
System->Configuration->Sales->Tax->Calculation Settings->Apply Customer Tax : After Discount

Comment: Hi alex, thanks for your input. We had set that as per your recommendation, but I still find something is wrong, for example, see the following screenshot: http://www.jasonshico.com/screenshot1.jpg and you will see the figures are just not right. I look forward to your next reply. Thanks once again. Cheers, Jason Shico

Comment: please share your tax configuration.

Comment: tax settings can be seen here; http://www.jasonshico.com/screenshot.jpg and then product tax information can be be found here: http://www.jasonshico.com/product_tax.jpg

Comment: Hi Alex, just wondering if you had a chance to review my tax settings? keen to touch base.